# Django in_bulk() raising error with distinct()

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following QuerySet:

```py
MyModel.objects
.order_by("foreign_key_id")
.distinct("foreign_key_id")
.in_bulk(field_name="foreign_key_id")
```

`foreign_key_id` is not unique on `MyModel` but given the use of `distinct` should be unique within the QuerySet.

However when this runs the following error is raised:

```
"ValueError: in_bulk()'s field_name must be a unique field but 'foreign_key_id' isn't."
```

According to the Django docs on `in_bulk` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.in_bulk) it should be possible to use `in_bulk` with `distinct` in this way. The ability was added to Django in response to [this issue ticket here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31918).

What do I need to change here to make this work?

I'm using Django3.1 with Postgres11.

Comment: The `.distinct()` part has only been added in Django-3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation of **`in_bulk(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.in_bulk) says:

> (…)
>
> **Changed in Django 3.2**:
>
> Using a distinct field was allowed.

Since you use [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1), this will thus not work, you will thus have to upgrade your program to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2).

Comment: ‍♂️ I saw `3.1` on the issue tracker ticket and thought that was the version with the fix in. Thanks, I'll accept the answer once stack allows it.